# Looking for Buddhist videos that explain the Buddhist view on consciousness in a clear succinct way

Tags: philosophy, consciousness

I am looking for Buddhist videos (by Buddhist monks preferably or lay teachers) that describe briefly (under 10 minutes) how Buddhists view consciousness.

Most I find are either lectures an hour-long, very difficult to understand, or poetic/allegorical.

I'm looking for videos like these. They are by Hindus explaining their view on consciousness briefly. Have you see something like these but Buddhist?

https://youtu.be/aGhm8CVnwck

https://youtu.be/9n6NvDpcwLM

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly multiple videos explaining consciousness, but none of them are short and concise. Try searching for "[ajahn consciousness](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ajahn%20consciousness)" on YouTube.

I would quote a few texts instead.

> “And what, bhikkhus, is consciousness? There are these six classes of
> consciousness: eye-consciousness, ear-consciousness,
> nose-consciousness, tongue-consciousness, body-consciousness,
> mind-consciousness. This is called consciousness.
> [SN 12.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.2/en/bodhi)

> “Bhikkhus, consciousness is reckoned by the particular condition
> dependent upon which it arises. When consciousness arises dependent on
> the eye and forms, it is reckoned as eye-consciousness; when
> consciousness arises dependent on the ear and sounds, it is reckoned
> as ear-consciousness; when consciousness arises dependent on the nose
> and odours, it is reckoned as nose-consciousness; when consciousness
> arises dependent on the tongue and flavours, it is reckoned as
> tongue-consciousness; when consciousness arises dependent on the body
> and tangibles, it is reckoned as body-consciousness; when
> consciousness arises dependent on the mind and mind-objects, it is
> reckoned as mind-consciousness. Just as fire is reckoned by the
> particular condition dependent on which it burns—when fire burns
> dependent on logs, it is reckoned as a log fire; when fire burns
> dependent on faggots, it is reckoned as a faggot fire; when fire burns
> dependent on grass, it is reckoned as a grass fire; when fire burns
> dependent on cowdung, it is reckoned as a cowdung fire; when fire
> burns dependent on chaff, it is reckoned as a chaff fire; when fire
> burns dependent on rubbish, it is reckoned as a rubbish fire—so too,
> consciousness is reckoned by the particular condition dependent on
> which it arises. When consciousness arises dependent on the eye and
> forms, it is reckoned as eye-consciousness…when consciousness arises
> dependent on the mind and mind-objects, it is reckoned as
> mind-consciousness.
> [MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/bodhi)

The way I see it, consciousness is the mind-body connection (where mind is "name" and body is "form" according to the definition in [SN 12.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.2/en/bodhi) and [SN 22.79](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.79/en/sujato)), and it's supported by:

> Name, reverends, is one end. Form is the second end. Consciousness is
> the middle. And craving is the seamstress, for craving weaves one to
> being reborn in one state of existence or another.
> [AN 6.61](https://suttacentral.net/an6.61/en/sujato)

And finally from [The Abhidhamma in Practice](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mendis/wheel322.html) by N.K.G. Mendis:

> Awareness is the process of *cittas* experiencing objects. For a *citta*
> to arise it must have an object (*aaramma.na*). The object may be a
> color, sound, smell, taste, something tangible, or a mental object.
> These are the six external objects. Strictly speaking a mental object
> can be an internal phenomenon, such as a feeling, a thought, or an
> idea, but as forming the objective sphere of experience they are all
> classed as external. Corresponding to these external objects there are
> six internal sense faculties, called "doors" since they are the
> portals through which the objects enter the field of cognition. These
> are the eye, ear, nose, tongue, body and mind. Each of the five
> physical sense faculties can receive only its appropriate object; the
> mind door, however, can receive both its own proper mental objects as
> well as the objects of the five physical senses. When a door receives
> its object, there arises a corresponding state of consciousness, such
> as eye-consciousness, ear-consciousness, etc. The union of the object,
> the door or sense faculty, and the consciousness is called "contact"
> (*phassa*). There can be no awareness without contact. For contact to
> occur all three components must be present — object, door, and
> consciousness. If one is missing there will be no contact. The process
> of the arising of consciousness and the subsequent train of events is
> analyzed in detail in the Abhidhamma. A study of this analysis will
> show that only "bare phenomena" are taking place and that there is no
> "self" involved in this process. This is the no-self characteristic of
> existence.